# How to calculate population standard deviation?

Tags: java, standard-deviation

Here is what I have so far. I need to use the number from a text file.

Calculations class:

```
public class Calculations {

    public void readFile(String fileName, double[] myArray) throws Exception {
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br;

    }

    public double computeStandardDeviation(double[] myArray) {
        double result = 0;

        return result;
    }

}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    private static int NUMBERS=20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] myNumbers =  new double[NUMBERS];
        Calculations calculations = new Calculations();
        try {
            calculations.readFile("numbers.txt", myNumbers);
            double stdDev = calculations.computeStandardDeviation(myNumbers);
            System.out.println("Population Std Dev = " + stdDev);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate the sum. Then, calculate the average square difference between each number and the mean. Return the root of this average.

Comment: I believe this actually is an answer. The question is "How to calculate population standard deviation" and Gavin Haynes actually answers this question. @GavinHaynes, could you please elaborate a bit more, so there is no doubt that you answer the question?  [- From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14300903)